# Getting numeric timezone in specified format

Tags: c++, c, unix, date, timezone

I would like to print the current time as `2011-08-18 10:11:12 -07:00`. I developed a code snippet as below,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void time_to_string(time_t clock,const char *fmtstr )
{
    char buf[256];
    if (strftime(buf, 256, fmtstr, localtime(&clock)) == 0)
        buf[0] = 0;
    cout << buf << endl;
}

int main()
{
        time_to_string(time(NULL), "%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S %z");
}
```

I am able to display the time as `2011-08-18 10:11:12 -0700` but not as `2011-08-18 10:11:12 -07:00`. Using `"%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S %:z"` produces `2011-08-18 10:11:12 %:z`.

How can i accomplish the above task in C/C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to manually split the string which is formated by `%z` as `+hhmm` or `-hhmm`. `%z` has a fixed format. Look at the [description of strftime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html).

> Replaced by the offset from UTC in the ISO 8601:2000 standard format ( +hhmm or -hhmm ), or by no characters if no timezone is determinable.

Build one string with date and time. Build a second string with the offset from UTC with `%z`, insert the `:` in the second string. Concatenate first and second string.

Answer (score 1):

It tries to interpret %: and it doesn't match a format specifier, so it prints it out as is. But you probably knew that already =)

In your time_to_string function, I would manually insert the ':' into the buffer before displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you tried don't exist.

What I would do is calling the function twice : once with `"%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S "`, and once with `"%z"`,  manually add the `:` in the second string, and then concatenate the two.

To insert the `:`, you could do an ugly buffer manipulation :

```
buf2[5]=buf2[4];
buf2[4]=buf2[3];
buf2[3]=':';

strcat(buf,buf2);
```

Note that the layout isn't likely to change for this specific data, so it's not so ugly.

0r if you *really* like overkill, a regexp. But you'll need an external library.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add the ':' at the end, modifying the result string. e.g.,

```
buf[26]='\0';
buf[25]=buf[24];
buf[24]=buf[23];
buf[23]=':';
```

I may be overlooking a better solution.

Comment: You should not make any assumptions about the length of the data in the buffer. You would need to zero the buffer before hand, and then determine where the end of the data was.

Comment: the `%z` wont change, but the problem is that if it's 7 am, the `%z` will be moved by one. and your code will fail.

Comment: I think this is a standard format, and if it's 7 am, 07 will be used instead of 7.